# Laravel Eloquent how to get data from 2 tables within a date range

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables (example) which have something like this... In the Invoice table, I have 5 records and in the Quotation table, I have 3.

| Invoice |
| --- |
| id |
| price |
| inv_desc |
| invoice_date |
| balance |

| Quotation |
| --- |
| id |
| qty |
| quo_desc |
| quo_date |

I want to get all records (*) from both tables between date 1/1/2021 and 28/2/2021, and save it in a single collection, in order to loop and display in list. Since the number of columns and name of the date column of the 2 tables are different, how do I retrieve the records sort by ascending dates? The expected output (example) should be:

| No. | Description | Quantity | Price | Balance | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Quotation | 5 |  |  | 1/1/2021 |
| 2. | Invoice |  | 154.90 | 154.90 | 12/1/2021 |
| 3. | Quotation | 10 |  |  | 23/1/2021 |
| 4. | Invoice |  | 456.00 | 126.59 | 5/2/2021 |
| 5. | Invoice |  | 126.59 | 56.70 | 23/2/2021 |

Comment: You have substantially changed your question.  Please show us the sample output you expect here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have already updated the question to show the sample output. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Can you include sample data in your question for invoice and quotation table on which the expected output should be derived

Answer (score 1):

You may try a union query:

```
$first = DB::table('Invoice')
    ->select('description', NULL, 'price', 'balance', 'invoice_date')
    ->where('invoice_date', '>=', '2021-01-01')
    ->where('invoice_date', '<', '2021-03-01');

$result = DB::table('Quotation')
    ->select('description', 'qty', NULL, NULL, 'quo_date')
    ->where('quo_date', '>=', '2021-01-01')
    ->where('quo_date', '<', '2021-03-01');
    ->unionAll($first)
    ->get();
```

This corresponds to the following raw MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT description, NULL, price, balace, invoice_date
FROM Invoice
WHERE invoice_date >= '2021-01-01' AND invoice_date < '2021-03-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT description, qty, NULL, NULL, quo_date
FROM Quotation
WHERE quo_date >= '2021-01-01' AND quo_date < '2021-03-01';
```

Comment: May I ask, what does union mean? Is it possible in one query?

Comment: @TanSiKai Check the update to my answer which now also shows you the raw MySQL query.  All I have done is to translate this query into Laravel code.

Comment: Does the unionAll() sorts the dates of the results?

Comment: No, you would need an `ORDER BY` clause for that, or, in Laravel, call `orderBy(...)`

Comment: But how can you order by date, since the name of date column of 2 tables are different? I think somehow need to select quo_date and invoice_date as the same name to sort them out? Anyway I have already updated the question so could you refer to it again? Sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: @TanSiKai just provide a common alias to both queries involved in union and the apply order by  on common alias , the order by is applied to the complete resultset, see updated answer

Comment: Union will not work because Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order.

Comment: @TanSiKai Answer has bee updated per your latest requirements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An error has occurred, Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list'. I also updated the question

Comment: ...and I have reverted your question.  Please stop changing it after others have answered.

Comment: The error occurred is the reason why I update my question. NULL in select statement is not working. I also see that you used description column in your select statement and I was wondering if the desc column is different, how should the query be made. As I have said the table I provided is just an simplify example, the real table I am working on is extremely complex. I understand when I created this simplified table, not much is being explained hence I try my best to include the details I left out.

Answer (score 0):

Since eloquent, what's the relationship between Quote and Invoice?
Would it be something like 1 quote will have many invoice? And I guess a Quote comes before an invoice.
if it is.

1. You will need to have to add another column in Invoice. so Quotation_id
2. Create your Quotation Model

> ```
> class Quotation extends Model
>
> {
>     use HasFactory;
>
>     protected $fillable = [
>         'qty',
>         'description',
>         'quo_date'
>     ];
>
>     public function Invoice()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
>     } }
> ```

3.Create your Invoice Model

```
    class Invoice extends Model
    {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'price', 'description', 'invoice_date', 'subtotal' 
    ];

    public function Quotation() 
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Quotation::class);
    }
}
```

4. Next in your Controller

```
    use App\Models\Invoice;
    use App\Models\Quoatation;
    
    $query = Quoatation::wherebetween('quo_date', [2021-01-01,2021-03-01])
    ->orderby('quo_date', 'ASC')->with('Invoice')
    ->wherebetween('invoice_date', [2021-01-01,2021-03-01])
    ->orderby('invoice_date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: 1 quotation 1 invoice. But some admins would delete quotation and leave the invoice. So number of quotation and invoice are not the same. Anyway, the number of invoices and quotations stated are just an example, I wanted to make sure the query I ask can also work when there are 2 different number of records in both tables

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer in another post that I asked, similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454203/15102985