# Laravel how to merge 2 collections

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 collections as below:

```
$unpaid = WhmcsClientsInvoice::join('quotations', 'quotations.id', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.quotation_id')
                    ->select('whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_id AS id', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_date AS date', 'quotations.total AS amount', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.payment_due_date AS due_date')
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.whmcs_client_id', $client_id)
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.status', '!=', 'Cancel')
                    ->whereBetween('whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_date', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                    foreach($unpaid as $un) { $un['type'] = "invoice"; }

                    $paid = InvoiceHistory::join('whmcs_clients_invoices', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.id', 'invoice_history.whmcs_clients_invoices_id')
                    ->select('invoice_history.id', 'invoice_history.date_paid AS date', 'invoice_history.amount_paid AS amount', 'invoice_history.created_at AS due_date')
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.whmcs_client_id', $client_id)
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.status', '!=', 'Cancel')
                    ->whereBetween('invoice_history.date_paid', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                    foreach ($paid as $paid) { $paid['type'] = 'payment'; }

                    $trans = $unpaid->merge($paid);
                    dd($trans);
```

But when I try to merge these 2 collections, an error will occur. [image: error of merge]

I tried `$transaction = $unpaid->union($paid)->sortBy('date');` but to no avail. Vardump of the merged collection shows:
[image: vardump img]

error_log the $transaction would show something like this:

> {"date":"2021-01-26
> 00:00:00","id":12,"amount":111.3,"due_date":"2021-01-26
> 09:00:05","type":"payment","0":{"id":1,"date":"2021-01-07","amount":222.6,"due_date":"2021-01-14","type":"invoice"},"1":{"id":3,"date":"2021-01-09","amount":6572,"due_date":"2021-01-16","type":"invoice"},"2":{"id":4,"date":"2021-01-12","amount":148.4,"due_date":"2021-01-19","type":"invoice"},"3":{"id":5,"date":"2021-01-12","amount":144.16,"due_date":"2021-01-19","type":"invoice"},"4":{"id":6,"date":"2021-01-16","amount":24.38,"due_date":"2021-01-23","type":"invoice"},"5":{"id":2,"date":"2021-01-29","amount":222.6,"due_date":"2021-01-14","type":"invoice"},"6":{"id":24,"date":"2021-02-23","amount":190.8,"due_date":"2021-03-02","type":"invoice"}}

Apparently the union merge the 2 collections, but couldn't assign key to the first item...
How do I merge 2 collections without missing any records in both collections? The expected output should be from this:

```
Collection {#595 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {
    "id" = 37
    "date" => "2021-02-07 00:00:00"
    "amount" => 50.0
    "due_date" => "2021-02-07 14:19:20"
    "type" => "payment"
    }
    2 => InvoiceHistory {
    "id" = 37
    "date" => "2021-02-07 00:00:00"
    "amount" => 50.0
    "due_date" => "2021-02-07 14:19:20"
    "type" => "payment"
    }
    1 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {
    "id" = 37
    "date" => "2021-02-07 00:00:00"
    "amount" => 50.0
    "due_date" => "2021-02-07 14:19:20"
    "type" => "payment"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing `invoice_history.id AS id`?

Comment: @RifatBinReza it is the same. Right now I am trying with union. The result I got is much closer to the solution. See the updated question

Comment: Can you do `$unpaid = collect($unpaid); $paid = collect($paid); $unpaid->merge($paid);`?

Comment: @RifatBinReza I think the merge has successfully merge 2 collections, just like how I did with union (see updated question). It failed to access to items due to how strange the structure of collection is after union or merge. There are 6 records from a collection and 1 record from another collection. Hence the 1 record from was not assigned with a key in collection

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes,

Try this

```
$trans = $unpaid->concat($paid);
```

Comment: I vardump it after concat and it shows this:

Collection {#587 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    8 => true
    7 => true
    9 => false
    10 => true
    0 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#589 ▶}
    1 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#569 ▶}
    2 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#568 ▶}
    3 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#567 ▶}
    4 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#566 ▶}
    5 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#565 ▶}
    6 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#564 ▶}
  ]
}

I think it is not supposed to have array item 7, 8, 9 and 10 with true or false initialized

Comment: try dd the result of unpaid before any operation you make 
and show me the result

Comment: dd($unpaid) would show something like this)
Collection {#583 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#589 ▶}
    1 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#569 ▶}
    2 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#568 ▶}
    3 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#567 ▶}
    4 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#566 ▶}
    5 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#565 ▶}
    6 => WhmcsClientsInvoice {#564 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: In the attributes section, it show something like this:
#attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "date" => "2021-01-07"
        "amount" => 222.6
        "due_date" => "2021-01-14"
        "type" => "invoice"
      ]

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of painstaking research, I found a way that works for me. This is my updated code:

```
$transaction = collect(new WhmcsClientsInvoice);
$unpaid = WhmcsClientsInvoice::join('quotations', 'quotations.id', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.quotation_id')
                    ->select('whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_id', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_num', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_date AS date', 'quotations.total AS amount', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.payment_due_date AS due_date')
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.whmcs_client_id', $client_id)
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.status', '!=', 'Cancel')
                    ->whereBetween('whmcs_clients_invoices.invoice_date', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                    foreach($unpaid as $un) { 
                        $un['type'] = "invoice"; 
                        $transaction->push($un);
                    }

                    $paid = InvoiceHistory::join('whmcs_clients_invoices', 'whmcs_clients_invoices.id', 'invoice_history.whmcs_clients_invoices_id')
                    ->select('invoice_history.date_paid AS date', 'invoice_history.remark', 'invoice_history.amount_paid AS amount', 'invoice_history.created_at AS due_date')
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.whmcs_client_id', $client_id)
                    ->where('whmcs_clients_invoices.status', '!=', 'Cancel')
                    ->whereBetween('invoice_history.date_paid', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                    foreach ($paid as $pa) { 
                        $pa['type'] = "payment"; 
                        $transaction->push($pa);
                    }
                    $transaction = $transaction->sortBy('date');
```

First, I make an empty collection based on WhmcsClientInvoices called Transaction. Basically, my idea is to create 2 separate collections, then merge them into Transaction. So, I made 2 eloquents to get 2 different collections. Then, during the foreach, I added a new item with key call type, to differentiate whether each record is invoice or payment. Then, I take each individual record in collection and push it to Transaction. I repeat the process with $paid collection. Lastly, I sort the collection by date.